# Gmail-like notification Service in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, wcf, notifications

I have a web-based application developed in `ASP.NET`.  It is a business application and people do regular deals & transactions from this portal.

The application has two types of user:

1) Front-office User - who makes the deal
2) Back-office User - who look at all accounting & voucher generation work for the deal

The current problem is, to check a new deal created by a front-office user, the back-office user needs to refresh the web page every few minutes, which is very time-consuming.

I want to develop a small windows-based notification service through which I can show them notifications without going to the browser. It will be in the same manner as the `Gtalk` desktop tool, which notifies us of newly-received mail.

So to achieve the above thing what should I use and how to use & implement the solution ?

I need to develop the solution using .Net framework

Answer (score 2):

I would look into SignalR and use that to keep a persistent connection open to your server and notify the client when new data is available. If you use SignalR, you don't even need a windows application, you can use their javascript client and show the notifications directly in the browser (you can of course still go the Windows Application route as well).

If you are in a cloud hosting environment, your cloud provider should have a service of use for you as well.

Comment: can you provide me sample for SignalR ? How tough the implementation is ?

Comment: Just Google SignalR and you'll find many samples. They have a few on their GitHub page. It's relatively straightforward, the framework takes care of all the dirty work for you

Comment: Thanks Ameen, I think this was perfect solution but for .net 4.5 and above. My application is in .net 4.0.